# VSC: JS: cannot find name require

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have a node script like this

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

var execSync = require('child_process').execSync;
```

Now when the file is named `script.js` VSC works fine, but when renaming it to just `script`, VSC shows the error

```
[js] Cannot find name 'require'.
```

I created a `.vscode/setting.json` with the following content:

```
{
    "files.associations": {
        "bin/infrastructure_destroy": "javascript"
    }
}
```

Now when I open `script`, the highlighting is correct on javascript, however, the error is still displayed. Renaming the file to `script.js` again removes the error.

Anyone here knows what I am missing? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an [issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7291) on GitHub for that.
The issue is already fixed in the backend language server but it seems that the fix isn't shipped yet.